# IOS Swift 3 Alamofire 4.0.0

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

Here is my code facing error at `NSMutable` line:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url!)
        request.HTTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json",forHTTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
        Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON{
            response in
            switch resposnse.result{
            case.Success(let data):
                print("Successfully grabbed response",data)
            case.Failure(let error):
                print("request failed with error\(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Please, can someone resolve my issue?

Comment: What is the issue you are experiencing? what has yoiu tried to solve it?

Comment: @Niryan Kindly response my answer that its working or not?

Comment: @EktaPadaliya thank you for the solution it did resolve my problem sorry for the late response

Comment: @NiryanValia Kindly accept my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use below code for Alamofire 4.0

```
Alamofire.request("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").responseJSON { (response) in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value) :

            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value as! [String:AnyObject]!{
                print("JSON: ",JSON)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("request failed with error\(error)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Alamofire.request( url, method: .get , parameters: nil, encoding:  JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON{
            response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                //some code
            }
        }
```